# How to synchronize MesageReceivedEvent from main EventListener with a new variable inside Thread only when it is updated by main's listener

Tags: java, multithreading, events, event-listener, discord-jda

I need to create a new Thread that will execute a method when and only when the MessageReceivedEvent is updated inside the main ListenerAdapter, and let the thread sleep whenever the variable is not updated.
This thread should run independently from the main thread and not stop new requests.

This is the thread class,

```
private static final class Worker extends Thread {

        private volatile boolean running = false;
MessageReceivedEvent event; //this must update along with the listener

        private boolean validateData() {
            if (//something) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void waitForInput() {

            boolean hasInput = false;
            try {
                while (!hasInput) {
                    hasInput = validateData();
                    if (!hasInput) {

                        Thread.sleep(10);

                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            running = true;
            while (running) {
                waitForInput();

                //do something

            }

        }

    }
```

It is an inner class ran by a request from the main thread,
the MessageReceivedEvent inside it must be updated only when the actual event from the listener changes, otherwise it should do nothing.
When testing, it will only execute based on the MessageEvent that triggered the thread, how can I make this thread receive the updates?

```
public class Listener extends ListenerAdapter {

    public static MessageReceivedEvent msgEvnt;


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent msgEvnt) {

                    Listener.msgEvnt = msgEvnt;
    }
```

This is all the listener does, update the variable whenever there is a new messageEvent.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to keep the event as a member of your thread?
If not you could use a BlockingQueue to handle your events. Your main thread can put events in the queue, while your dedicated thread will block until some element is put in the queue using method `take()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Condition Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables_2) to accomplish this.

```java
final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

private void waitForInput() {
    lock.lock();
    Listener.msgEvnt = null;
    try {
        while (Listener.msgEvnt == null)
            condition.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        Listener.msgEvnt = msgEvnt;
        condition.signal();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

> See [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

---

You can use a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

```java
final BlockingQueue queue = new ConcurrentBlockingQueue();

private MessageReceivedEvent waitForInput() throws InterruptedException {
    return queue.take();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    queue.put(event);
}
```

---

You can use a [Callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)), this is what I would recommend.

```java
Consumer<? super MessageReceivedEvent> callback;

private void onInput(Consumer<? super MessageReceivedEvent> callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    if (this.callback != null)
        this.callback.accept(event);
    this.callback = null;
}
```

Example use:

```java
listener.waitForInput(event -> {
    System.out.printf("%#s: %s\n", event.getAuthor(), event.getMessage().getContentDisplay());
});
```

This is already provided by [JDA-Utilities](https://github.com/JDA-Applications/JDA-Utilities)